# Silly, can't figure out php round down :(

Tags: php

I have small problem and it might be silly somewhere, but still i have it :)

So the problem is:

By doing this

```
round(615.36*0.10, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

I expect outcome to be `61.53`, but it's `61.54`.

```
phpVersion = 5.3.2
```

Could anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` will round the **half** -- i.e. the `0.005` part.

if you have `61.535`, using `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` will get you `61.53` -- instead of the `61.54` you should have obtained with *usual rounding*.

Basicall, the `.005` **half** has been rounded down.

But **`61.536` is not a half** : `.006` is more than `.005` ; so rounding that value gives `61.54`.

---

In your case, you could multiply the value by 100, use the [**floor()**](http://fr.php.net/floor) function, and divide the result by 100 -- I suppose it would give you what you expect :

```
$value = 61.536;
$value_times_100 = $value * 100;
$value_times_100_floored = floor($value_times_100);
$value_floored = $value_times_100_floored / 100;
var_dump($value_floored);
```

Gives me :

```
float(61.53)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round down, you'll need to use floor(), which doesn't have a means to specify precision, so it has to be worked around, eg. with

```
function floor_prec($x, $prec) {
   return floor($x*pow(10,$prec))/pow(10,$prec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you obviously only wanting it to two decimal places why not just number_format(615.36*0.10, 2)

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i want, but since was not my question i can only give you upvote. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work, as it rounds up: `float 15.315315315315`  => `string '15.32'`